# Size of GrouBox in different resolution vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resolution, groupbox

I have question, why in other computer with 1920x1080 resolution are GroupBox bigger than in image 1. 
In picture 2 doesn't showing blue text "Kniha".. But resolution of forms are same.

[image: This is right solution]

[image: This is wrong but why?]

Comment: Possibly because both computers have a different dpi font scaling setting for their operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I think **Anchors** are what you need. It will adjust automatically the location or size of an object based on its container.

Syntax:

```
YourControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom + AnchorStyles.Left
```

But based on your design, I will suggest that you make your form sizes compatible to all resolutions.